# How to Preserve a Complex Line During Shapely Intersection

Tags: python, geometry, intersection, shapely, geos

I'm trying to intersect a complex line with a polygon using the Shapely library in Python. Unfortunately Shapely breaks my original line so that it returns a simple line instead.

For example:

```
# complex line folded back on itself (A-B-A)
ls = shapely.geometry.LineString([(1,0), (1,2), (1,0)])
ls.length == 4.0

# intersected with a covering bounding box
bounding_box = shapely.geometry.Polygon([(0,0), (0,2), (2,2), (2,0)])

intersected = bounding_box.intersection(ls)
# LINESTRING (1 0, 1 2)  - (A-B)
intersected.length == 2.0
```

You can see that the duplicated component in the original line is gone. I can understand where that behaviour comes from and it's probably the sane choice in most cases.

I'm looking for a way to do the intersection so that I retain the original line information. In this degenerate case I would expect to end up with exactly the same geometry back, a line of length 4 folded on itself. In other more complex cases the polygon I'm intersecting with will slice up the original line, but I still need to retain any duplicated segments within the intersection.

Comment: Your line is non-simple (i.e. `ls.is_simple is False`), which is why the overlaps are not preserved. You may need to extract the line overlap segments, which doesn't sound easy.

Comment: That's the approach I used. Actually, will post below. Originally I actually stacked up a load of lines in 3 dimensions hoping that they would all be sliced independently. Shame it doesn't work, would be super helpful in my case!

Answer (score 0):

For the moment I'm doing it brute-force by doing the line segments 1-by-1.

```
segments = [shapely.geometry.LineString(x) for x in zip(line.coords, line.coords[1:])]

for segment in segments:
    intersected = polygon.intersection(segment)
    # ...
```

Seems like a problem that should be easy to vectorize!